# How to synchronize Nokia smartphone with a PC?

Tags: qt, qt4, synchronization, symbian, smartphone

I want to develop an application using Qt and deploy it on both Symbian S60 smartphone and PC. I want the instances to synchronize their data when devices connected. I don't care about connection type (USB, Bluetooth, etc.). Does Ovi Suite provide a service for the task? Or could I use some Qt API for that? I know that Ovi can synchronize *files* between devices, so I could use a file system as a transport, but I'm looking for a more elegant way of doing sync.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own PC application using [Nokia PC Connectivity API](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/Other/PC_Connectivity_API/). It should be able to access files on the S60 device.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple guide for your aim: 
http://www.dndc.it/CalSync.pdf
Hope it helps !

Checco (Francesco) Dotti